# Как настроить SSL соединении в PostgreSQL на Windows между клиентом и сервером

Tags: windows, postgresql, ssl

Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос как настроить SSL соединении в PostgreSQL на Windows между клиентом и сервером, я с генерировал уже сертификат и ключ но никак не могу найти инструкцию что дальше делать(

Answer (score -1):

Я использую pgAdmin. Я не использую SSl, а подключаюсь через vpn на прямую по IP. Я посмотрел документацию там стандартная настройка, смотрите
[скришот меню настройки](http://joxi.ru/Vm6z5Vbtx3wwMm). Просто заполните его.

Comment: да, я также использую pgAdmin.

Comment: Все равно ничего не получается(